# Как разместить тег 'p' в блоке 'div' таким образом, чтобы блок не растягивался и текст отображался корректно?

Tags: html, css3, html5

Всем доброго времени суток!

**Суть проблемы:** Я желаю разместить тег 'p' в блоке 'div' таким образом, чтобы div не изменялся в размерах и содержащийся в нём текст отображался с необходимыми для меня размерами (достаточными для удобного распознавания символов). Из-за размещения внутри блока тега 'p' происходит расширение блока. Поскольку блок расположен в grid и каждая ячейка сетки имеет размеры в 1fr*1fr, при растягивании одного блока идёт растягивание и всех остальных блоков. Это приводит к тому, что страница скролится и извращает дизайнерский замысел. Наверняка многим мой вопрос покажется типичным и глупым, однако я всё же осмелюсь задать его.

**Вопрос:** Как разместить тег 'p' в блоке 'div' таким образом, чтобы div не изменялся в размерах и содержащийся в нём текст отображался с необходимыми для меня размерами? Мне бы подошла любая реализация, но если понадобится, то я могу выложить фрагмент своей разметки. Также буду рад любым ссылкам и советам!

Comment: Фрагмент разметки точно не помешал бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поставь `<div>` стиль `display: inline-block;` или же задай `max-width:` с тем значением которого он не должен превышать. Точнее можно было бы сказать если бы показал в задаче html css